# HTML5: Show hint text near to cursor

Tags: html, gwt

I am looking for a way to show a text (hint) that moves with the cursor.
Is there a way to do it with GWT or native HTML5?

Comment: There are a lot of jQuery plugins, but no such thing in native html. I don't know about GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the ability to do tooltips (if that's what you're looking for) with straight CSS and HTML.

[Linky.](http://aninnovativeweb.tumblr.com/post/820491172/semantic-tooltips-with-pure-css3-and-html5)

I can't confirm I've used this before, but the code would be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>I <span data-tooltip=", really" class="tooltip">really</span> like pie.</p>​
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip:hover:after { content: attr(data-tooltip); }
```

[Here's a jsFiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/gY56r/)

Answer (score 5):

Just use HTML **title** Attribute in any html tag like this:

```
<p title="I'm giving you a hint!">text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In GWT, create a Label with CSS style "position: absolute". Attach a MouseMoveHandler to it. In this handler set label's position next to the cursor. Don't forget to add this label to your view when you want it to appear.

```
Label label = new Label("My hint that moves");
label.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);

label.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
        label.getElement().getStyle().setTop(event.getClientY(), Unit.PX);
        label.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(event.getClientX(), Unit.PX);
    }
}
```